# Reset (reset to previous value) only the form fields that are changed

Tags: javascript

I need to reset only the form fields that are changed (reset to previous value).

I tried to use the reset but it completely resets the entire form and I don't need this.

How can I do this?

```js
function clearResult() {
            document.getElementById("save").reset();
        }
```

```html
<div class = "container">
         <form method="post" id="save" onload="onLoad()">
             <div class="field">
                 <label for="id"> ID:</label>
                 <input type="number" id="id" name="id" />
             </div>
             <div class="field">
                 <label for="type"> Fragment Type: </label>
                 <input type="text" id="type" name="type" />
             </div>
             <div class="button">
                 <button type="submit" class="full">Save changes</button>
                 <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="clearResult()" />
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
```

Comment: Do you send this form to somewhere else or just handle in javascript on form submit event?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN is an edit form. As soon as the page is opened, the values appear in the fields. I want that if I change a field, it returns me to the original value (i.e. the value I get when I open the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should to store the predefined values of form elements to set them back when you want to reset them back.

Then you can use this globally defined initial values to set them back whnever reset event occurs.

```
var id, type;
const form = document.getElementById('save');

document.onload = (event) => {
  id = form.id.value;
  type = form.type.value;
};

function clearResult() {
  form.id.value = id;
  form.type.value = type;
};
```

Comment: i get this error:: The specified value "[object HTMLInputElement]" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

Comment: @a_l_e_x edites my code above. Could you try again please?

Answer (score 0):

It was simple. When page load just get values from that fields.
Make with **document.onload**:

```
var firstValue = document.getElementById("yourFieldId").value;
```

After form submit get values like below:

```
var currentValue = document.getElementById("yourFieldId").value;
```

And after submit in reset check if **CURRENT VALUES** equal with **VALUES FROM FIRST TIME**
*Example*

```
if(firstValue != currentValue){
  document.getElementById("yourFieldId").value = firstValue;
}
```